# How can I print a single field?

Tags: theming, taxonomy-terms, 9

I've got a taxonomy page (https://www.dovericaricare.it/becharge) that I'm trying to customize using a twig template.

I don't understand what syntax I should use to print fields like the logo
(`{{ fields.field_logo }}` doesn't work and there is nowhere in the dump a field with a full path url for the image) or the value of `field_fornitore`

Here's the dump of the content of the page (you can see it on the page itself too). Can you please suggest how to print values in twig template?

(I already did the same on a node page, but the taxonomy term seems a lot harder)

[image]

Comment: Normally you print just `{{ content }}` and use the vocabulary's display settings to put your fields in the right order and select the desired field formatters. Maybe together with some [Field Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) if you need additional wrappers. You can also print `{{ content.field_logo }}` exclusively and later print the rest `{{ content|without('field_logo) }}`.

Comment: The variable would be {{ content.field_name }} to render a field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the code I used at the end (don't remember how I get it, but I remember that KINT debugger helped me a lot):

```
{# start to cycle #}
{% for immagine in content.field_immagine_colonnine %}
    {% if immagine['#item'].target_id > 0 %}
        <div class="imagetext">
            <img alt="{{ immagine['#item'].alt }}" 
                title="{{ immagine['#item'].title }}" 
                src="{{ file_url(immagine['#item'].entity.uri.value | image_style('large') ) }}" 
                id="{{ immagine['#item'].target_id }}" 
            />
            <p class="sottotitoloimmagine">{{ immagine['#item'].title }}</p>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{# end cycle #}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your field_logo has got a list (array), where is your logo.
I would try

`{{ content.field_logo[0] }}`

If you want some helpful forum with more info about references (and entities for nodes as well) look there:
https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/theme-development/2015-12-16/entity-reference-values-in-twig-template